# PHP exec() nohup with redirect

Tags: php, exec, stdout, stderr, nohup

I am trying to execute a command with exec() and redirecting stdout and stderr to a file.

`exec("nohup python main.py -i 1 > /var/scripts/logs/1_out.log 2>&1 &");`

It will create the file but it will not print anything to it.

If I run the command in a terminal everything outputs without a problem.

Comment: Try adding `</dev/null` to the command string, essentially redirecting _all_ IO streams (stdin is not redirected by default)

Comment: Still nothing.  `exec("nohup main.py -i 1 > /var/scripts/logs/1_out.log 2>&1 </dev/null &");`

Comment: And is there any nohup.out file (the default file nohup redirects the stdout to)

Comment: Check my answer. Got it working by using the -u option for python which disables the output buffer from python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. Python does its own output buffering which kept it from writing to the file. Running it with the -u option disables this. Final code looks like this:

`exec("nohup python -u main.py -i 1 > /var/scripts/logs/1_out.log 2>&1 </dev/null &");`

Thanks.